# How to access row data in before_save_instance for Django Import Export

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I'm trying to use [django-import-export](http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to load data into my Django site admin interface.

During the input I want to do some complicated data validation which involves creating and/or modifying other models related to the one being uploaded into with django-import-export.

It seems like the `before_save_instance` hook is the time in the [import workflow](http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import_workflow.html) that I want to perform this complicated validation.

`before_save_instance`'s input parameters include only the object for the model being updated, which does not contain all the data from the row being imported.

In particular I don't see the read only fields from the row being imported anywhere (and I need them for my validation logic).

How can I get access to the entire row being imported from inside of `before_save_instance`?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out you can get a list of the fields on the object in question with:

`self.get_fields()`

And you for a given `field` you can access the values for the `instance` passed into `before_save_instance` with:

`field_value = None
try:
    field_value = field.get_value(instance).all()
except AttributeError:
    field_value = field.get_value(instance)`

You can also override the `before_insert_rows(self, rows, **kwargs)` method to get access to the raw row information.

Comment: Excellent find, maybe to late to ask, but how would u change a given field in all rows before saving it? Say u want to do .upper() to all ModelSample.name columns in all rows before importing ?

Comment: I get the actual `field` using this `my_field = self.get_fields()[0]` what is a better way?